# I Would Like to Generate a Cross Reference List for the Variables in a JavaScript File

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a free or to-purchase utility that generates a variable cross reference list
for a JavaScript file.  For example, here is some sample code.

```
function storePositiveNumbers(x)
{
   // put positive numbers in array y
   // exclude a if a<=0
     n = arguments.length;
     ct = 0;
     for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if (x[i] > 0) {
           ct++;
           y[ct]=x[i];
        }
     }
}
```

I would like the cross reference table to look something like this:

- Non-array variables: n, ct
- Arrays: x, y
- For-loop variables: i

The cross reference table would exclude:

- object names, object properties
- anything in quotes or comments

Thank you.

Comment: Just use JSDoc.

Comment: Also, why do you want a listing of _every local variable_? This sounds like someone really misunderstands the ISO 9001 process... or a subpar software-analyst is trying to make busywork to justify their position.

Comment: Hi Dai,  I'll check out JSDoc.  Ideally, the cross reference list would also indicate what functions the variables are located in.  I can envision various uses for a utility like this.  At present I simply want to know what is available.

Comment: I personally can't see the need for a dedicated utility or tool for this because that functionality is already baked-in to most JavaScript IDEs already for their "Go to symbol" feature. Most JavaScript language-servers do this already, for example.

Comment: I use Notepad++.  The View Menu allows me to see functions but not variables.  I don't use any other JavaScript IDE.